# Internal Mic not working Ubuntu 20.04, Razer Blade 15 base ~2020

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, realtek

I have been using Ubuntu for a while; this is not a new install. The mic worked perfectly in a Zoom meeting yesterday. Today it was unresponsive.
In system settings the mic test is also unresponsive. I suspect it has nothing to do with the app.

Found this [microphone is not working on ubuntu 20.04 in lenovo-g50-70](https://askubuntu.com/q/1341554/1290281) and it describes a similar issue on different system. I also ran `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec` got the output

```
Codec: Realtek ALC256
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
Codec: Nvidia GPU 99 HDMI/DP
```

Unlike Abhishek; I have no idea where to begin editing the alsa~conf file.
Does anyone have a generic answer, or insight into this?

[image: screenshot showing lack of microphone volume in sound menu]

Comment: I tested mic function in Audacity as well. It records mono white noise.

Comment: The microphone slider in 'system mixer' menu is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the next daily update cycle.

Not sure this qualifies as an answer but; after much research, updating, debugging, infinite restarts, and exploring countless *.conf files...
It just started working.
I have no idea why it failed, or why it started working again.

--Theory:
I also see an intermittent bug in the wifi on startup. I think some resource is being allocated incorrectly. Or unrelated software packages are trying to share something that should not be shared.

I should also note that the sound problem has appeared a few times this past year. Usually after updating the Zoom application. Coincidence? Maybe it's cleanup is removing a critical file that the system needs?

Apologies to the community for my non-answer. I will monitor to see if anyone has more insight.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the 'non-answer'. I have this problem too, but am new to the community and cannot upvote due to lack of reputation. Help me out?

But yes, several times I have also noted that the mic works fine (internal to the laptop AND bluetooth headphones) but then some days it just doesn't. Super annoying to sit on a zoom like a dope without a mic and then ask for a minute to boot back to windows...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: Hello Honey badger, wish I had a clear insight. I still suspect that the zoom update process itself is somehow the cause. I have just learned to either not screw with it right before the meeting, or allow time to purge, reinstall and restart. The complete process is important if I am the host. --Zoom does have it's own volume controls baked in. I think that is what is not compatible with our systems. It could be kernel or window manager related. I wonder if XFCE or Cinnamon users get this also ?